# Create a coordinate system or diagram from values in an existing table

Tags: tables

I have a table in a document that looks like this:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htpb]
\centering
\captionabove{occurrence of X by year}
\begin{tabular}{||c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c||}
\hline
1915-1991 & 1992-1998 & 1999 & 2000 & 2001 & 2002 & 2003 & 2004 & 2005\\
0 & 8 & 7 & 12 & 24 & 32 & 35 & 44 & 65\\
\hline
2006 & 2007 & 2008 & 2009 & 2010 & 2011 & 2012 & 2013 & 2014\\
79 & 106 & 126 & 147 & 158 & 150 & 170 & 205 & 219\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to take the exact same values and elegantly put them in a **coordinate system** where the horizontal axis is *year* and the vertical axis is *occurrence*, or in a **bar graph**?

Or, what would be the best (understandable, eye-pleasing) way in a document to convey the information from this table?

Comment: Two things that came to my mind: I would prefer your table to be transposed, that is having two columns instead of two rows. (My opinion :))
Second, my idea for solving your problem would be to export your data to a textfile (`.csv` for example) and use some packages to produce the table and your bar graph. Maybe `csvsimple` might do the former, while `tikz` should be able to do the latter - I don't know for sure, though...

Comment: @cauchy42 Problem with the two columns instead of two rows: I have several similar tables, and some of them have more years, but they all have only one value per year (or year group). So they’d take up a large vertical space if ordered vertically.

Comment: @cauchy42 Thanks, I’ll take a look at how to use csvsimple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not very eye-pleasing, but a point to start:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{csvsimple}    
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{filecontents*}{mytab.csv}
Year, Data
1915, 0
2002, 32
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}

\csvautotabular{mytab.csv}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    ]

    \addplot table [x=Year, y=Data, col sep=comma] {mytab.csv};
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Major problem with this code is, that you cannot have year ranges like 1915-1991 in the table, as tikz is interpreting these as floating point numbers. There is surely a way around this, but I don't know tikz good enough to tell.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Your example looks simpler than I thought it’d have to be. Maybe if we made tikz treat 1915-1991 as a string, it could work? I’m not sure how that would be done, though.

Comment: @Philipp you might **possibly**  have a third column with tick labels, and the first column contain only the start year (or just an integer)...